# Diffusion limit of asymmetric random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus, random-walk

The symmetric binomial random walk is a canonical derivation of Brownian motion,
$$dX_t = dB_t$$

Is there some way to derive a diffusion process from an asymmetric random walk? It seems like the asymmetry would work its way into the drift term $a$ in the diffusion,
$$dX_t = at + bdB_t$$

But at the same time the Brownian motion term itself, in the canonical derivation, comes from the $1/2$ probability of the random walker moving left and right. So some of the asymmetrical motion should also contribute to the $dB_t$ term.